# Question mark issue with ADOdb and MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, adodb-php

I'm running into an issue with ADOdb's PHP library (https://sourceforge.net/projects/adodb/) and MSSQL Server 2012

I'm doing a simple update statement with a placeholder, just like this one, but it fails saying I didn't give enough parameters to the Execute function:

`UPDATE report SET custom='Is this ok?' WHERE ID = ?`

I checked the adodb-mssql.inc.php and in the Prepare function it simple replace every ? with the @P syntax for MSSQL, instead of checking what is a Placeholder and what is not:

```
function Prepare($sql)
{
    $sqlarr = explode('?',$sql);
    if (sizeof($sqlarr) <= 1) return $sql;
    $sql2 = $sqlarr[0];
    for ($i = 1, $max = sizeof($sqlarr); $i < $max; $i++) {
        $sql2 .=  '@P'.($i-1) . $sqlarr[$i];
    }
    return array($sql,$this->qstr($sql2),$max,$sql2);
}
```

So in my query I get 2 @P params (@P0 inside the quotes (not intended as a placeholder), @P1 as the real placeholder), resulting in already said error since I only give the Execute function 1 parameter to replace instead of two.

Is this a know limit of the ADOdb library? Do I have to check every field and replace the question mark not used as placeholder with something different before executing the query or am I missing something?

Comment: This is a known limitation of endless tools that emulate prepared statements using dumb string replacement. But this looks too bad to be true. Are you sure you've grabbed the latest version available?

Comment: 5.18, upgrading to 5.20 right now just to test if this has been somehow fixed, but the Prepare function looks the same in both version. 

EDIT: Upgrade to 5.20, same issue:
Warning: mssql_query(): message: Must declare the scalar variable "@P1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been [browsing the code](https://github.com/ADOdb/ADOdb/tree/v5.20.3). This library is terribly outdated (it's written for PHP/4!) and the mssql driver is particularly bad. You might have better luck if you can use the PDO or SQLSRV drivers (at least they appear to use native prepared statements) but I guess it's an existing legacy app or you wouldn't be using such library in the first place.

If you can't switch drivers (or doing so doesn't solve the issue) I think you'll have to live with the bug and pass static strings as parameters as well, turning this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE report SET custom='Is this ok?' WHERE ID = ?";
```

... into this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE report SET custom = ? WHERE ID = ?";
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are trying to access the database via FreeTDS or similar, you are using the wrong driver. You should be using the mssqlnative ADOdb driver, which was originally submitted to the project by Microsoft.

If you are still having problems, you should submit an issue at [Github](https://github.com/adodb/adodb/issues), to see if this can be resolved in the driver